# Remove elements in an ndarray based on condition on one dimension

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

In a Numpy ndarray, how do I remove elements in a dimension based on condition in a different dimension?

I have:

```
[[[1 3]
  [1 4]]

 [[2 6]
  [2 8]]

 [[3 5]
  [3 5]]]
```

I want to remove based on condition `x[:,:,1] < 7`

Desired output (`[:,1,:]` removed):

```
[[[1 3]
  [1 4]]

 [[3 5]
  [3 5]]]
```

EDIT: fixed typo

Comment: I'm not sure how to connect your condition to your desired output: there is only one element smaller than 7. Does that mean the second dimension gets removed entirely?

Comment: Do you mean `x[:,:,1] < 7`? Because your example has all True conditions.

Comment: Yes, x[:,:,1] < 7. Typo. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `[1, :, :]` removed instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your desired output, you filter `x` on axis=0. Therefore, you may try this way

```
m = (x[:,:,1] < 7).all(1)
x_out = x[m,:,:]
```

Or  simply

```
x_out = x[m]   

Out[70]:
array([[[1, 3],
        [1, 4]],

       [[3, 5],
        [3, 5]]])
```

Answer (score 2):

This may work:

```
x[np.where(np.all(x[..., 1] < 7, axis=1)), ...]
```

yields

```
array([[[[1, 3],
         [1, 4]],

        [[3, 5],
         [3, 5]]]])
```

You do get an extra dimension, but that's easy to remove:

```
np.squeeze(x[np.where(np.all(x[..., 1] < 7, axis=1)), ...])
```

Briefly how it works:

First the condition: `x[..., 1] < 7`.
Then test if the condition is valid for all elements along the specific axis: `np.all(x[..., 1] < 7, axis=1)`.
Then, use `where` to grab the indices instead of an array of booleans: `np.where(np.all(x[..., 1] < 7, axis=1))`.
And insert those indices into the relevant dimension: `x[np.where(np.all(x[..., 1] < 7, axis=1)), ...]`.